# How to remove java.lang.NullPointerException when taking values from servlet to jsp

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am getting values from servlet to jsp. My intention is to take value through form, after submitting form the value come inside totalperiod string variable. I want to take that value to jsp page but it shows an error. After running project instead of showing form its shows below error.
In java, inside doPost

```
String period=request.getParameter("totalperiod");
 request.setAttribute("value", "period");
```

In jsp,

```
int tenure =(Integer) request.getAttribute("value");
```

error at console

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException

An exception occurred processing JSP page /home.jsp at line 160     
160:      int tenure =(Integer) request.getAttribute("value");
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
String period = request.getParameter("totalperiod");
request.setAttribute("value", period);
```

In JSP check for NullPointerException

```
if (request.getAttribute("value") != null) {
   int tenure = (Integer) request.getAttribute("value");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all there is a wrong value set

```
String period=request.getParameter("totalperiod");
 request.setAttribute("value", "period");
```

it should be like below if you want to response back the value of period

```
String period=request.getParameter("totalperiod");
 request.setAttribute("value", period);//without ""
```

It can be done many ways, but just an example to pass value back to jsp

```
String period=request.getParameter("totalperiod");
request.setAttribute("value", period);
request.getRequestDispatcher("home.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

and in jsp page, you can check to ensure whether data arrived or not

```
int tenure=-1;
if (request.getAttribute("value") != null) {
   tenure = (Integer) request.getAttribute("value");
}
```